# Read values from resx files?

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

How to read strings from the MyResource.resx file from c#.
I am not calling this from the asp.net page, rather i am calling from my bussiness logic.

> Assembly assembly =
>   this.GetType().Assembly;
>   
>  ResourceManager resourceManager = new
>   ResourceManager("MessagesResource",
>   assembly);
>   
> resourceManager.GetString("SCHEME_UNQ");

here i am getting exception,

> Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "MessagesResource.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly "App_Web_eerdggo8" at compile
>   time, or that all the satellite
>   assemblies required are loadable and
>   fully signed.

How can i fix this issue????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you add a resx file to your project, Visual Studio will automatically generate a designer class which allows you to read value (In the properties of the resx file you must have `Custom Tool: ResXFileCodeGenerator`). For example if you add `Messages.resx` to your project you could directly read values from it:

```
string value = Messages.SomeResourceKey;
```

Comment: i not reading the resource file from the aspx page. I am trying to read this from my BussinnessLogic.cs(Bussiness Logic layer).

Comment: Is the resource file defined in the Web Tier?

Comment: yeah.. its there in the App_GlobalResources folder. Is this the right way to read..? Is it possible to read the resource file using Resource Mangaer??

Comment: In order to read a resource file defined in another assembly you will need to have reference to this assembly, meaning that in your case the business logic tier will need to have a reference to the web tier assembly which is bad. Either place the resources file in the business tier and use the technique I've demonstrated or deport this logic into the web tier.

Comment: ok.. If i move the resource file into the bussiness logic layer...
how can i read the file???

where can i find the CustomTool:ResxFileCodeGenerator??

Comment: In the properties of the resx file, but you probably don't need to modify it as this is the default value. As to the way you read from it, you use the strongly typed class generated by Visual Studio.